# Can you explain what happens with 2019 and what it is?

Tags: c

No compilation and runtime errors

Is 2019 is kind of variable or anything?
Explain this please

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    a= b = 2020, 2019;
    printf("%d %d", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52550/1216776

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Comma Operator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Comment: I can explain 2019, but 2020 is still a mystery.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = b = 2020, 2019;
```

Is parsed as:

```
(a = (b = 2020)), 2019;
```

The `,` is a [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator). First the left side of `,` is executed, it's result is discarded, a sequence point happens and then the right side is executed. So let's execute the left side:

First the inner braces need to be executed, ie. `b = 2020` is executed, ie. `b` is assigned the value of `2020`. The [simple assignment operator `=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) "returns" the same value that was stored, ie. in this case `b = 2020` returns the value `2020`. So now we have:

```
(a = 2020), 2019;
```

Then `a = 2020` is executed - `a` is assigned the value of `2020`. So now we have:

```
2020, 2019;
```

The result of the left side of comma operator is ignored (and side effects happen). So now we have:

```
2019;
```

It's just a value, something one could call an "empty statement" or "empty expression". A single value doesn't do anything, it is permitted by the language grammar and is like just ignored. Mostly empty statements with a `(void)` cast are used to remove compilers warnings about unused variables, they are used like `int unused; (void)unused;` - the `(void)unused` is just an expression that doesn't do anything.

> Can you explain what happens with 2019

Nothing.

> and what it is?

A [rvalue](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#note53) of type `int`. A expression that has type `int` and value `2019`.

> Is 2019 is kind of variable or anything?

It's not a variable, it's just an expression. Try it out, any number is an expression, like `int main() { 1; 2; 3; 1.0; 1 + 1; }`